# Loading Picture in Screen using SOIL in C++ does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, 64-bit, soil

using SOIL library I tried to load an Image below the Grid that I drew; 
this is the code for this function:

```
void ModelGL:: LoadTexture()
{
        texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("images/GolSa.png",SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);

        //if(texture[0] == 0)
        //exit(1);


    // Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //Bottom Face (true)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

but in output I do not see the picture;

Answer (score 1):

before or after `glBindTexture(...)` try `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)`

edit:
Being that you are using `glTexCoords*(...)` you have to enable them first with `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before using them.

Here is an example of a textured cube:
http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131768/understanding_and_using_opengl_.php?print=1
Read the section `A First Try at Texturing`

Comment: it is undeclared identifier